# showing the values in google-chart treemap

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, treemap

I have created a Treemap using google charts.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Location', 'Parent', 'Market trade volume (size)', 'Market increase/decrease (color)'],
  ['Global',    null,                 0,                               0],
  ['America',   'Global',             20,                               0],
  ['Europe',    'Global',             30,                               0],
  ['Asia',      'Global',             10,                               0],
  ['Australia', 'Global',             40,                               0],
  ['Africa',    'Global',             30,                               0],
]);
tree = new 
google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'select', function () {
  tree.setSelection([]);
});
tree.draw(data, {
  headerHeight: 15,
  fontColor: 'black',
  showScale: true,
  maxDepth: 2
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows the tree map as:
[image]

Now, I want to show the values of Market trade volume (size) as well on the treemap (without any action of the mouse). since It has only one layer so directly value can be shown without any calculation.
I searched in the documentation but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: @WhiteHat yes, I want to show --> Australia(40) -- instead of just --> Australia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a couple assumptions are made here...

1) you do not want to show the value for Global --> `Global(0)`
2) you don't want to modify the values in the data table or how it is loaded

using object notation, we can provide the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

the chart will display the formatted value, but use the value when determining tree order

this allows us to change the display without affecting the relationships,
in case you have data with more than one layer...

as such, a `DataView` is used to modify the values
use the `setColumns` method to provide a calculated column for the label

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var rowValue;

    if (row === 0) {
      rowValue = dt.getValue(row, 0);  // value for global
    } else {
      // change display value by changing formatted value
      rowValue = {
        v: dt.getValue(row, 0),
        f: dt.getValue(row, 0) + '(' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + ')'
      };
    }

    return rowValue;
  },
  label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
  type: data.getColumnType(0)
}, 1, 2, 3]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['treemap']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Location', 'Parent', 'Market trade volume (size)', 'Market increase/decrease (color)'],
    ['Global',    null,                 0,                                0],
    ['America',   'Global',             20,                               0],
    ['Europe',    'Global',             30,                               0],
    ['Asia',      'Global',             10,                               0],
    ['Australia', 'Global',             40,                               0],
    ['Africa',    'Global',             30,                               0],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var rowValue;

      if (row === 0) {
        rowValue = dt.getValue(row, 0);  // value for global
      } else {
        // change display value by changing formatted value
        rowValue = {
          v: dt.getValue(row, 0),
          f: dt.getValue(row, 0) + '(' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + ')'
        };
      }

      return rowValue;
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: data.getColumnType(0)
  }, 1, 2, 3]);

  var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'select', function () {
    tree.setSelection([]);
  });
  tree.draw(view, {
    headerHeight: 15,
    fontColor: 'black',
    showScale: true,
    maxDepth: 2
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to WhiteHat for putting me on the right track. Using his answer I've found another way to achieve this that deviates less from the original example.

This also allows nesting by the ID. In the example below, you can USA displays as 'United States of America', but the states below link back up to the 'USA' id.

More importantly for me is that it gives the ability for 2 items to have the same label. Notice there is a London in Europe>UK and America>Canada>Ontario.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Location', 'Parent', 'Market trade volume (size)', 'Market increase/decrease (color)'],
                ['Global', null, 0, 0],
                ['America', 'Global', 0, 0],
                ['Europe', 'Global', 30, 0],
                ['Asia', 'Global', 10, 0],
                ['Australia', 'Global', 40, 0],
                ['Africa', 'Global', 30, 0],
                [{ v: 'USA', f: 'United States of America' }, 'America', 20, 0],
                ['Mexico', 'America', 24, 12],
                ['Canada', 'America', 16, -23],
                ['Ontario', 'Canada', 12, -9],
                ['Alberta', 'Canada', 24, 13],
                ['UK', 'Europe', 21, -5],
                [{ v: '123', f: 'London' }, 'UK', 21, -5],
                [{ v: '456', f: 'London' }, 'Ontario', 21, -5],
                ['Ohio', 'USA', 12, 3],
                ['Rhode Island', 'USA', 24, 4]
    ]);
    tree = new 
    google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    tree.draw(data, {
                    minColor: '#f00',
                    midColor: '#ddd',
                    maxColor: '#0d0',
                    headerHeight: 15,
                    fontColor: 'black'
    });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```